# Photomagnetic effect

Tags: electromagnetism, photoelectric-effect, solar-cells

I just saw an article on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomagnetic_effect

"This article appears to contain unverifiable speculation and unjustified claims. Information must be verifiable and based on reliable published sources. Please remove unverified speculation from the article."

Ok, but there is also link to the article:

http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2011/apr/21/solar-power-without-solar-cells

Could someone tell me if this is some serious science or just a hoax?

Comment: It's suspicious to me that all of the references on Wikipedia are from the same month and the paper has only been cited once in three years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone tell me if this is some serious science or just a hoax?

This is definitely serious research and not a hoax.

[Professor Steven C. Rand](http://www.lsa.umich.edu/physics/directory/faculty/randstephen_ci) is a physics department faculty member at University of Michigan.  [His research group](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~scr/) studies ceramic materials using laser pulses.

His publications, which are listed in the above links, include peer reviewed articles in mainstream journals such as Journal of the Optical Society of America and Journal of Applied Physics.